# Incremental scaling function

Tags: java, numerical-methods

If you know that 'input1' is strictly between 0 and 1 or generally, 'min' and 'max' (where min and max are known to be between, but not strictly, 0 and 1), how would you get 'input1'to increment or decrement by a numerical jump given by 'input2' with assurance that the new value is strictly between min and max and will never reach min or max?

Comment: What are the limits on input2? If input2 can be greater than `max` or less than `-1 * min`, what is the rule for handling that?

Comment: input2 > 1, you're function would need to deal with keeping the result between min and max

Comment: I'm still unclear. If `input1 = 0.7`, `max = 0.75` and `input2 = 2.25`, what should the result be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function), preferably an invertible one (the inverse is called [quantile function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function)).
In other words, you need a monotone strictly increasing, continuous function f with `lim[x->-oo] f(x) = 0` and `lim[x->oo] f(x) = 1`.

If you have such a distribution function f and its inverse f⁻¹, then your adjusting function gets something like this:

```
g (x, Δ) = f( f⁻¹(x) + Δ )
```

This is for values between 0 and 1, for other intervals `[a, b]` we need to scale it, using a scaling function `s`:

```
s(x) = (b-a)·x + a,     s⁻¹(y) = (y-a)/(b-a)
```

Then the adjustment function gets

```
h(x, Δ) = s(g(s⁻¹(x), Δ) = s( f( f⁻¹(s⁻¹(x)) + Δ )).
```

One easily Java-calculable such distribution function would be

```
f(x) = 1 - 0.5 * exp(-x)   for 0 ≤ x
f(x) =     0.5 * exp( x)   for x ≤ 0
```

with the quantile function

```
f⁻¹(y) = - log(2 - 2y)  for   y ≤ 0.5
f⁻¹(y) =   log(2 y)     for 0.5 ≤ y
```

Building from this your adjustment function is just putting these together.

Of course, this works only to the limits of your number precision – you can't get arbitrary close to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should keep input1 within `min/max`

```
input1 = ((input1 - min + input2) % (max - min)) + min;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use min/max like

```
 public static int adjust(int n, int adjust, int min, int max) {
      return adjust0(n, adjust, min+1, max-1);
 }

 private static int adjust0(int n, int adjust, int trueMininum, int trueMaximum) {
      return Math.max(trueMininum, Math.min(trueMaximum, n + adjust));
 }
```

This will allows you to adjust your values and be sure it will be between min and max but never those values.

Comment: This surely does not *never reach max or min*.

Comment: If it never reaches the maximum or minimum then its not the maximum or minimum. I will update the example. ;)